# How can I create a data structure containing properties whose types are defined at runtime

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic, reflection

I am working on a data visualisation tool. It retrieves a bunch of data from a plain text file and then draws various charts and graphs of that data.

So far I have been working with one set of data of which I know the types.

For example if I'm working with a CSV file that looks like this:

id, username, number of messages, message 
23123124, @SomeUsername, 5, This 1s a 5tr1ng
89134349, @AnotherUsername, 8, Another string

Then I can store this in an object like this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private string id;
    private string username;
    private int numberOfMessages;
    private string message;
}
```

Then I just have a `List<SomeClass>`.

That's great and everything, but it will only work with that particular CSV file. I want to have a data structure that can be flexible, depending on the contents of the CSV file.

The number of properties and the names of those properties is easily discovered by reading the header row in the first line of the text file. What type each piece of data is isn't clear (e.g. an id could be stored as an int or a string), so I'm going to ask the user to tell the application what type to use for each property. I could do this by displaying the name of each property next to a dropdown with options of string, int, bool etc.

But how do I take that user input and create a data structure that contains properties of those types. So if the user goes through a form with 3 drop downs and selects "String", "Integer" and "Boolean", I effectively want an object that looks like this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private string someString;
    private int someInt;
    private bool someBool;
}
```

What is the best way of achieving this? I have a reasonable understanding of **Generics** but not sure how to use them in this case. I have heard of **Reflection**, the **Type** class and the **dynamic** keyword but don't really understand them. I have tried using Dictionaries but keep getting stuck. Are any of these options viable? Are they overkill? Am I overthinking this? **HELP ME PLEASE!** :D

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a fixed set of csv files to deal with or are you dealing with a number of csv's with a random number of columns and data types? i.e. can you say.. this is report type1,2,3 etc.. each one then has a known set of columns?

Comment: Also, have you just considered using strings for the initial csv loading?

Comment: @Wheels73 the CSV files are out of my control. They will be provided by the user. So the number of columns and what types they should be stored as is unknown to me. I could initially load the CSV file values as strings but I would then need to convert them to the correct type as defined by the user.

Comment: You could use an interface or baseclass and introduce new derived types using `Reflection.Emit`. This approach has its charms but is probably expensive in terms of complexity.

Comment: Morning... So bare with me... why do you need to convert them into the correct types? What do you need to do with "SomeClass" after its populated?

Comment: do you still need help with this?

Comment: @Wheel73 Yes I do still need help with this. I will try to explain why I think I need to convert them to the correct types, but maybe I'm wrong about that. My application takes the data and draws a bunch of bar charts and pie charts etc. Data visualisation stuff. So, I need to be able to categorise the data in certain ways. For example, if there is a column that contains a Date, I would like to be able to store it as a Date so that I can do Date operations on it. E.g. display a graph showing only the data where that Date value is before a certain date.

Comment: @Wheel73 Or if there is a column that contains integer values, it would be great if I could perform maths on them. If I know they are integers, I could show a graph where I sum the values of multiple data items and display that as a single entity on a graph. Let's just say for example I have a data file containing a list of User Accounts from a forum with usernames, date registered, number of posts etc. It would be nice to be able to sum the number of posts of each user to get the total number of posts made by all users.

Answer (score 1):

When you read the csv file you could have a list which contains a dictonary.
Little example ...

```
List<Dictionary<string, object> yourDataInAList = new List<Dictionary<string, object>();
//... you now read the csv file and iterate the file
Dictonary<string, object> dynamicDataStructure = new Dictonary<string, object>();
// ... you iterate now through the values in the entry ...
dynamicDataStructure.Add(yourHeaderName, yourValue);
// ... at the end of the itereation through the values in the entry we have to add
// this dic in the list
yourDataInAList.Add(dynamicDataStructure);
```

No complexity but a lot of flexibility :) But you have to be aware that the header shouldn't have multiple same names in it ...

Comment: So, do you suggest just casting the objects to the appropriate type when needed? I think I will also have to store a dictionary of header names and types specified by the user (I could make this an enum of common types). Then whenever I need to do a type-specific operation on the data I can check the dictionary of header names and types and then cast to the type specified. I think this will work but it feels really messy and also I think it would lead to other problems... hmmm.... :\

Comment: You could use "as" and check if the variable is null like
int i = dynamicDataStructureObject as int
if(i != null) // i is a int :)